# display: inline-block with alternate flows at low media width

Tags: css

`inline-block` is the awesomest CSS tag ever. (That mean I only learned how it works last night. But then I threw away dozens of lines of HTML in preference to it.) It lets blocks reflow!

How do we write a banner that collapses into a different order when the screen is too small?

Big screen

```
[ A ][ B ][ C ]
```

Small screen?

```
[ C ]
[ B ]
[ A ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tx to whoever first mentioned 'flex'. I still like my previous `float:` solution, and SW4's will also work - IF you can find a way to float the divs together. But it's `flex` that allows you to re-order things.

Furtherless, `@media` & similar systems (such as `50%`), reference the current page size (probably A4), not the current window size. I want to be so responsive that we behave like the mobile app, even if we're just a generic browser that someone scrunched up. So we need JS - the arch-nemesis of CSS - to trigger the changes.

The trick is `display: flex;` enables `order:`*N*`;`. That means switching the container to `display: inline-block;` will turn on document-order:

```
<script>
    function resizeMe(win) {
      var size = $(window).width();
      var display = size > 600 ?  'inline-flex' :  'inline-block';
      $('#flexMe').css({ display: display });
    }
    $(window).bind('resize', resizeMe);
    $(window).bind('load', resizeMe);
</script>

<div id="flexMe" style="display: flex; width: 100%;" >
    <div id="hdrLogo" class="hdrLogo hdrNv" style="order: 3; width: 375px;" >
        Logo goes here
    </div>

    <div id="hdrAuth" class="hdrNv" style="order: 2; width: 375px;">
        Login stuff goes here
    </div>

    <div id="hdrNavBar" class="hdrNv" style="order: 1; width: 375px;">
        Record navigator goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

That way the Record Navigator is either upper left, or closest to the records, and the Logo is either upper right, or farthest from the records.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some HTML and CSS trickery for the order switching, and then you could simply use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), with e.g.:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Ra6TL/2/)

HTML

```
<div>D</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>A</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:50px;
    width:25%;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:right;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    div {
        display:block;
        width:100%;

    }
}
```

By having the elements in reverse order, then using `float:right` in your CSS, it places them in the order you anticipate- which is then ignored when they are given 100% width on screen resize- so they appear in the DOM (reverse) order.

Comment: a note to the newbs: To see the effect in a fiddle you gotta drag the drag bar between the source and the output panel. Thanks, SW4!

Comment: another note: if you throw away the `@media` check, and add a `min-width: 50px;`, you get the exact effect I sought.